# Airflow parallelism failuer while changing the DB to postgres

Tags: postgresql, airflow, airflow-scheduler, parallel-execution

I have installed airflow locally and I am changing the executor to run parallel tasks
For that, I changed

1- the Database to Postgres 13.3

2- in the config file
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost/postgres

3- executor = LocalExecutor

I have checked the DB and no errors
using
airflow db check -->  INFO - Connection successful.
airflow db init --> Initialization done

Errors that I receive and I don't use SQLite at all

1- {dag_processing.py:515} WARNING - Because we cannot use more than 1 thread (parsing_processes = 2 ) when using SQLite. So we set parallelism to 1.

2- I receive this error from airflow web-interface

```
The scheduler does not appear to be running.
The DAGs list may not update, and new tasks will not be scheduled.
```

So shall i do any other change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually restart your Airflow webserver/scheduler after you changed the config?

Answer (score 0):

The following logging statement:

```
{dag_processing.py:515} WARNING - Because we cannot use more than 1 thread (parsing_processes = 2 ) when using SQLite. So we set parallelism to 1.
```

It comes from [Airflow 2.0.1 with the following code fragment](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.0.1/airflow/utils/dag_processing.py#L514)

```py
if 'sqlite' in conf.get('core', 'sql_alchemy_conn') and self._parallelism > 1:
    self.log.warning(
        "Because we cannot use more than 1 thread (parsing_processes = "
        "%d ) when using sqlite. So we set parallelism to 1.",
        self._parallelism,
    )
    self._parallelism = 1
```

This means that somehow, it is still on 'sqlite' based on your `[core] sql_alchemy_conn` setting. I think if you are certain you changed the `airflow.cfg` and restart all airflow service, that it might be picking up another copy of an `airflow.cfg` then you expect. Please inspect the logs to verify it is using the correct one.